# Error PHP en buscador MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

recientemente logré crear un buscador mysqli en php.
El problema es que si encuentra mas de 1 resultado simplemente pone el mismo id de usuario y nombre.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
   if($_POST["username"] !=""){
      include "conexion.php";
      $buscar = $_POST["username"];
      $sql1= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Username LIKE '%$buscar%'";
      $query = $con->query($sql1);
      if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
          echo "Resultados para: $buscar";
          do {
              ?>
              <br>
              <br>
              (ID: <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>) - <?php echo $row['Username']; ?>
              <?php
          }
          while (mysqli_fetch_array($query));    
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";             
        }
    }
}
```

Supongamos que yo ingreso "hola" y en la base de datos hay 3 usuarios registrados con el nombre "hola" "hola1" "hola2", el código me daría esto:

```
    Resultados para: hola 

(ID: 2) - hola 

(ID: 2) - hola 

(ID: 2) - hola
```

En vez de darme algo como esto

```
(ID: 2) - hola 

(ID: 3) - hola1

(ID: 4) - hola2
```

Espero que se logre entender, desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda o ten presente que el operador LIKE funciona del siguinte modo:

1. LIKE '%cadena' va a buscar coincidencias de la palabra al final
2. LIKE 'cadena%' va a buscar coincidencias de la palabra al inicio
3. LIKE '%cadena%' va a buscar coincidencias en toda la palabra

> Entonces dado que tu estas buscando que aunque el listado de palabras
>   sea **hola hola1 hola2**, no quite el número y te lo muestre así.

Entonces tu query debería quedar del modo siguiente

```
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Username LIKE '$buscar%'";
```

Te anexo el pequeño ejemplo que hice

```
select * from ejem where saludo LIKE 'ho%';
+--------+
| saludo |
+--------+
| hola1  |
| hola2  |
| hola3  |
+--------+
```

También lo puedes hacer del siguiente modo e igualmente obtendrás el resultado esperado

```
select * from ejem where saludo LIKE '%ho%';
+--------+
| saludo |
+--------+
| hola1  |
| hola2  |
| hola3  |
+--------+
```

> El único operador que no te va a servir para lo que necesitas es:

```
select * from ejem where saludo LIKE '%ho';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: No se si no te entendí o simplemente soy yo.

Te muestro un ejemplo más claro y mas cerca del error que tengo.


Yo tengo 3 usuarios con el siguiente nombre : Rodrigo_Hola - Rodrigo_Holaa - Rodrigo_Holaaa.

Cuando yo realizo la busqueda me aparecen 3 resultados pero simplemente me los muestra así:

(ID: 2) - Rodrigo_Hola

(ID: 2) - Rodrigo_Hola

(ID: 2) - Rodrigo_Hola


(Imagen para que me entiendas más fácil: http://prntscr.com/jiscnc - http://prntscr.com/jisczl)

Comment: cuentame tu dudas y te apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Como se puede ver, te está repitiendo el primer registro porque no estás recuperando bien los datos.

Cuando haces una consulta, generalmente el resultado es una especie de puntero colocado en el primer registro. Ese puntero hay que recorrerlo, creando por ejemplo un array con los datos que hay en él y luego hay que leer ese array.

En tu código nunca pasas del primer registro por ese motivo.

Prueba haciéndolo de este modo:

```
#Creamos un array con el cual llenaremos cada fila
$rows = array();
$result = $con->query($sql1);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    #Aquí dentro del bucle, se recorren los resultados y se agregan a $rows
    $rows[] = $row;
}

#Nuestra variable utilitaria, para escribir código limpio y legible
$strHTML="";

#Si no se encontraron datos, $rows será false y entrará en el else
if ($rows){ 
    #Concatenamos esto a nuestra variable utilitaria fuera del bucle for
    $strHTML.= "Resultados para: $buscar";
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        #Seguimos concatenando
        $strHTML.="(ID: ".$row['ID']."-".$row['Username'].")".PHP_EOL;            
    }

}else{

    $strHTML="No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";      
}
#Imprimimos la información que se ha ido recogiendo
echo $strHTML;
```

He corregido algunas cosas, como la mezcla de estilos de programación con respecto a mysqli, usando solamente el estilo orientado a objetos.

También, le he dado más claridad al código, usando una sola variable que concatena los resultados y los imprime al final.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias por ayudarme. Se habrá notado que estoy aprendiendo php. +1

Comment: Una pregunta, puedo separar el texto sin necesidad de usar otro echo? Me refiero a esto:http://prntscr.com/jislig

Comment: Si te refieres a ponerlo en otra línea , agregas un salto de línea con `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Agregue un `PHP_EOL` al final de ésta línea `$strHTML."Resultados para: $buscar\n".PHP_EOL;` Pero sigue saliendo junto con la otra.